# Result the second element of a list in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
list = [['John','Barnes'], ['Bob','Marley'], ['Chris','Brown']]
```

I would like to use x as a variable for the first element and the result will be the second element of that list.

```
x = input("Type the first name")
```

Then print the second element. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I suggest using `raw_input` instead of `input`, Python 2.X will call `eval` on the result of your input and you may get unexpected NameErrors.

Comment: @jacob: not Python 3.

Comment: @vaultah Thank you for making it clear that it is different depending on the Python version.

Comment: Please don't name a variable `list` since it will shadow the `in-built list object`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That list is easily convertible to [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict). The simplest approach I can think of:

```
In [14]: names = dict(list) # first name -> second name

In [15]: x = input('Type the first name: ')
Type the first name: Bob

In [16]: names[x] # search the `names` dictionary and return the second name
Out[16]: 'Marley'
```

---

If you don't want to convert `list` to dictionary, a simple loop would look like

```
x = input('Type the first name: ')
for first, second in list:
    if first == x:
        print(second)
        break
```

It can also be written as a [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression):

```
In [19]: x = input('Type the first name: ')
Type the first name: Bob

In [20]: next(second for first, second in list if first == x)
Out[20]: 'Marley'
```

Dictionary lookups are usually faster than this and you should use the first solution if you can.

Also, try not to use names of built-in types (e.g. `list`) and functions as variable names.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The list to dict works really well!

Answer (score 2):

If that's what you wanted:

```
x= raw_input("Type the first name\n")
print ''.join([i[1] for i in list if i[0] == x ])
```

Input:

> John

Output:

> Barnes

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you could do it with `re` module and `list comprehension`:

```
import re

l = [['John', 'Barnes'], ['Bob', 'Marley'], ['Chris', 'Brown']]
x = 'Bob'

result = [l1[1] for l1 in l if re.findall(x, l1[0])]
print(result)
['Marley']
```

Or you could just compare it with x:

```
result = [l1[1] for l1 in l if l1[0] == x]
['Marley']
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic way to do this would be :

```
# It would not be correct to name the list of names as 'list'
l = [['John','Barnes'], ['Bob','Marley'], ['Chris','Brown']]

#get the input and convert it into lowercase
x = input("Type the first name").lower()

#A function that prints the last name , if there is a match , Note : This would also print the last names for all first name matches.
def get_last_names_for_first_names(x):
      for first_name,last_name in l:
         if (first_name.lower() == x):
             print (last_name)
```

That's about it .